# NodeJS prometheus metrics and grafana false metrics peaks

Tags: node.js, prometheus, grafana, prom-client

i am experiencing really strange behavior with prometheus and grafana. It seems like when prometheus gets under load from grafana e.g. when changing date range to larger or refreshing the graphs after longer time, it generates false metrics, it directly affects the data that prometheus has, as it can be retrieved changed also directly in prometheus.

[image: metrics peaks]
I am using basic promQL nothing special e.g.
The metrics I am using are custom, created in node.js by prom-client.

```
avg(rate(udp_uplink_receive_duration_seconds_bucket{ success="true"}[1h]))
```

But as it can be seen on all of the graphs it looks like something affects all the metrics when under load.

prometheus settings

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     5s
  evaluation_interval: 30s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: nodejs 
  honor_labels:true
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['...']
```

there is definitely nothing generating the data from the apps.

any help what to check? is there any config i am missing ?

Comment: Make sure the metrics and their types match the graphs that you are using, and what is the exporter for your Node.js application? Please provide a little more information about the tools and your approach.

Comment: I am using mostly histograms. and timeSeries graphs. But it affects all the metrics not only graphs but also stat widgets, ... As i mentioned also when i look up the metrics directly in prometheus it is affected. i am using prom-client for custom metrics and for express integration and monitoring express-prom-bundle